# How to send file by wp_remote_post?

Tags: curl, wp-remote-post

### I don't want cURL in my WordPress plugin

Hi, cURL is not safe to use on WordPress site. And sometime, cURL has been disable on customer hosting.

### And i decided to use wp_remote_post to send file for my plugin

Here my code :

```
$service = URL SERVICE ;

 $headers = array(
            'accept'       => 'application/json', // The API returns JSON
            'content-type' => 'application/binary', // Set content type to binary
        );


$data     = array(
                'headers'  => $headers,
                'body'     => file_get_contents($image_file),
            );
$response = wp_remote_post($service, $data);
```

But on server, i cannot received file from wp_remote_post. Please help me fix this issue ? How i can config to send file from wp_remote_post same as CURLFile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution for this issue, i using wp_remote_post to send binary of file to server.

When processing data received on server, i use this code to get data of file

```
$file = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

And i write it to temp file

```
$temp   = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $file);
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($temp);
```

Do you have any other solution ? Please discuss with me to find best answers.